# How do I call an stored procedure from another stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a main stored procedure that insert 3 varchar fields, name, address and phone number and other 3 fields that insert an ID from foreign keys in a table, these 2 foreign key fields also use an insert stored procedure to insert their own data. How do I call those stored procedures from the main SP to insert the varchar fields and the foreign key fields generated when executing them?

```
Table 1          Table 2         Table 3
id,              id2,            id3,
name1,           name2,          name3, 
address1,        address2,       address3,
phoneNumber1,    phoneNumber2,   phoneNumber3
id2,
id3,

create procedure table1    
@id int,
@name1 varchar(30),
@address1 varchar(100),
@phoneNumber1 varchar(30)
as
    BEGIN
set nocount on;

Insert into table1
           (id,
           name,
           address,
           phoneNumber)
    values(
           @id,
           @name,
           @address,
           @phoneNumber)
    END

------After inserting the data into table 1, I want to call the SP of table 2 and 3---

EXEC SPTable2
```

Answer (score 2):

From the main procedure:

```
Insert into table1 (...)
exec yourProcName @param='foo'
```

You should have each proc return the data set you need and the main proc call each of them and do an `INSERT INTO` as I showed above.

The table definition of `table1` has to match **exactly** the number of columns and data types of the result sets returned by the other procs.

If you can't guarantee this condition, you are probably better off writing a function that returns a table so that you can do a `insert into table1 (....) select col1, col2, etc from fnFoo(@param)`

Comment: The other procedures also insert data in their own tables basically I just want to execute them from the main SP to do the insertion of the 3 varchar fields and the id's of the table 2 and 3

Comment: @arturor when you say 'data in their own tables' do you mean temp tables? But again, if it's all a matter of calling the procs to have them do their thing on their own, just do `exec yourprocname`. I hope you are not referring to `global temporary tables` because that's seldom a good idea. Imagine your proc running concurrently...

Comment: No, they are not temp tables and they have their own SP to insert the data

Comment: @arturor Then I don't see the issue. BTW, I don't recommend you name a stored proc the same as a table. It's a good practice to prepend `usp` (user stored procedure) -or another indicator that suits you- to differentiate procs , function, views, etc.

Comment: Ohh ok, then I just add EXEC SPTable2 and then EXEC SPTable3

Comment: @arturor If I understood correctly your problem, the answer is yes.